# Check for JSON values with different response in swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I have a get method

```
AF.request("https://adamas-intl.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/coupons", method: .get
            , parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

                   switch response.result {

                   case .success(let json):
                    print("Validation Successful",response.result)
 case let .failure(error):
                       print(error)
                   }
```

The response result is different when there is value from the get method as follows:

With value:

"ADAMAS10"

Without value:

[]

How to check for the value of the response as without value is shows empty array else it shows a  string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an `else if let` clause to check this scenario as follows.

```swift
if let string = json["key"] as? String {
    print("String", string)
} else if let array = json["key"] as? [String] {
    print("array", array)
} else if let dictionary = json["key"] as? [String: Any] {
    print("dictionary", dictionary)
}
```